# Why f-strings are slow compared to % notation?

Tags: python, string, performance, formatting, cpython

I have been thought that f-strings are faster than other ways of string formatting.

Recently I have done a small research. The result was a surprise -- small code with f-strings takes more time than percentage notation. Can someone explain the reason why?

The code is following:

```py
from timeit import repeat

setup = 'i = 1.34234324'

for code in ["'%f %f' % (i, i)", "f'{i} {i}'"] * 5:
    t = min(repeat(code, setup, number=10000)) / 10000
    print(f'{int(t*1e9):4} ns ', code)
```

The print result is :

```
 321 ns  '%f %f' % (i, i)
 782 ns  f'{i} {i}'
 322 ns  '%f %f' % (i, i)
 786 ns  f'{i} {i}'
 321 ns  '%f %f' % (i, i)
 779 ns  f'{i} {i}'
 320 ns  '%f %f' % (i, i)
 782 ns  f'{i} {i}'
 320 ns  '%f %f' % (i, i)
 780 ns  f'{i} {i}'
```

I use Python 3.10.7

I expected that f-strings would have greater performance.

I also would like to get the answer which way of float substituting into a string is the fastes.

Comment: Why would you have expected  different result? And in what way is one sample sufficient evidence for anything?

Comment: Do they really give you the same result?

Comment: If you use `%` and then the fstring, both variants are equally fast (sometimes one is faster, sometimes the other is faster). This is not a reliable way to benchmark

Comment: Please use [this code](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9NbsIwEIX3PsVTpMhx5LaEBAmQchLEglJbnYV_ZCYLVOUkbNjAUXoHboMJ8KT52cz35p2u8ci_wZ_Pl4Htx_L2b1NwYHKGGORiSIxkotmxEAfDQ0QPSbk1n203b7t23kkhbEjYhx8D8tgUsrQorUSJijRIFRqFlX80IpcstqixWAtkcQY58tXToXogNCYbDT-4b5P6ZpalFL4wbdNZTOS5eiDz4LoxK7XuRvgDpJ7-UM80r1DvcHc) in your question instead.

Comment: @knittl Try mine.

Comment: @knittl Or just see the updated question now.

Answer (score 1):

Look at below two snippets of code.

it will be slower for floats since f-string

does not truncate the float

and guarantees some 16 digits of precision

in all other cases it will be much faster

```
i=1.645649846546786534646568684564688646546548686465416574786
a=f"{i}"
print(a)

1.6456498465467866
```

```
i=1.645649846546786534646568684564688646546548686465416574786
b="%f"%(i)
print(b)

1.645650
```

You may ammend the code to following for

proper comparison use %f with 16 decimal points precision

`"'%.16f %.16f' % (i, i)"`

```
import timeit

timeit.timeit('a=f"{i}"',setup='i= 1.645649846546786534646568684564688646546548686465416574786',number=100000)
0.04724510000005466


timeit.timeit('a="%.16f"%(i)',setup='i= 1.645649846546786534646568684564688646546548686465416574786',number=100000)
0.03985800000009476

### f-string is comparable %
```

Comment: "Doesn't truncate" is likely not the full explanation, they might use entirely different algorithms. But yes, I'd say the important thing is they do different things.

Comment: I thing you have a mistake 'i= "1.645649846546...."'
No need in double quotes.
It's better to test with
`timeit.timeit('a=f"{i:.16f}"',setup='i= 1.645649846546786534646568684564688646546548686465416574786',number=1000000)`

Comment: yes they would be doing different algorithms. But also default %f essentially is like giving %.6f  with 6 decimal points of precision .. and when you actually do a %.16f for 16 decimal points of precision its comparable

Comment: @Настя Крылова  you are right my mistake.. actually its a shade slower... than % but not over 2x times as pointed out in the question

Comment: @geekay Also, you should not use f-string in second timeit. This  `a=f"%.16f"%(i)` has to be `a="%.16f"%(i)`